# How to get json data in iOS?

Tags: ios, json

**DATA :**

```
2 =     {
        "delivery_cost" = "Free Delivery";
        "delivery_cost_aed" = "0 DHs";
        "delivery_time" = "24 hours";
        "payment_modes" = "[{\"icon\":\"216.70.96.219\\/_media\\/images\\/ico\\/ico_pm_cod.gif\",\"label\":\"Cash On Delivery\"},{\"icon\":\"216.70.96.219\\/_media\\/images\\/ico\\/ico_pm_cod.gif\",\"label\":\"Cash On Delivery\"}]";
        "product_price" = "1,400 DHs";
        "product_url" = "http://www.mygsm.me/Htc-Flyer-16GB.html";
        "shop_id" = "o2md-0qwq-9qam-y5m1";
        "shop_logo" = "216.70.96.219/_media/images/shop_logos/ShopLogos_07.gif";
        "shop_url" = "mygsm.me";
        shopname = "Mygsm.me";
        stock = 1;
        "total_cost" = "1,400 DHs";
        warranty = "216.70.96.219/_media/images/ico/warranty/1.png";
    };
```

**GET VALUE :**

I want to get all **icon url** from **payment_modes** in array. LIKE THIS

216.70.96.219\/_media\/images\/ico\/ico_pm_cod.gif

216.70.96.219\/_media\/images\/ico\/ico_pm_cod.gif

Comment: @ChiragDj You have big answer GOOGLE and SO.

Comment: @SAMIR RATHOD i did not downvote your question

Comment: yes you are right.. you did downvote on my question not answer. tu pakaday gyo bhai....

Comment: @ChiragDj you have to mention which JSON you are used. JSON,NXJSON or other...

Comment: Use a JSON parser.  There are at least a half-dozen to choose from, including Apple's NSJSONSerialization.

Comment: @SAMIRRATHOD - There is only one JSON, the one described at json.org.  There are many parser packages for JSON.

Comment: But it appears that you already have the JSON parsed, as the above listing is of an NSDictionary.  You'd use `objectForKey:@"2"`, followed by `objectForKey:@"payment_modes"` to fetch the item you want.

Answer (score 1):

You want to goole the NSJSONSerialization class. Your code will look something like this:

```
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                          options:kNilOptions
                          error:&error];

    NSArray* commands = [json objectForKey:@"foo"];
```

Notice that I had an array in my JSON, but it could just have easily been a dictionary.

Comment: The OP has already parsed the JSON into an NSDictionary, as can be seen from the dump listing.

Comment: Yes. Given how little effort that the OP put into the question I put similarly minimal effort into the answer. I figured that pointing out the NSJSONSerialization class was probably enough but putting in a lmgtfy link would be a bit cheeky... :- )

Answer (score 0):

To convert a json string to Foundation objects

```
NSString *jsonString = ...;
NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonString options:0 error:nil];
NSArray *payment_modes = [dict objectForKey:@"payment_modes"];
```

Comment: The outer dictionary element has the key "2".